Proofing that the interior of a convex cone united with the origin is a convex cone also (does the proof suffice?)
(One of my colleagues said that it's just clever renaming and I've tried to adapt someone else's proof; but I'm not sure if I'm showing what I should. And I'm not sure I know what I should actually show.)
So our goal is to show that $ka$ is also contained in the interior of the cone if $a$ is already.
Or rather: "Show that there exists an $\epsilon^*$ such that $B_\epsilon^* (ka)$ is still within the interior of the cone."
We begin the proof:
Our $a$ is in the interior, so there also exists an $\epsilon$ > 0, so that the  $B_\epsilon(a)$ is in the interior.
(I'm still clear on that.)
(Now I start to become a bit unsure.)
We choose  $y \in$ $B_\epsilon^* (ka)$. We say that $\Vert y-ka\Vert$ = $\delta$ < $\epsilon^*$ . We redefine $y$ and $\delta$, such that $y=kx$ and $\delta$=$k\epsilon$.
$\Vert y-ka\Vert$=$\Vert kx-ka\Vert$= $|k|\Vert x-a \Vert$ = $\delta$
It follows from redefintion that $\Vert x-a \Vert$ = $\epsilon$. So x is contained in $B_\epsilon (a)$.
$kx=ka+k\epsilon= ka+\delta=y$. (Sorry, what is going on? This is copied from a colleague)
And then he says it follows that the epsilon ball around ka is also in the interior. (#)
(Beforehand we proved that the interior of a convex set is also convex, and together with that # follows)
I'm just really confused by that whole thing - I understand that we try to redefine our elements such that we get the desired statement but are our conclusions actually correct and what we want?
Any help would be highly appreciated!
